useSWR isnot working in Firefox and Safari. NextJS App
I use useSWR to get data from my backend and I noticed that in Safari and Firefox my request is not even sent, but when I use google chrome everything works perfect. What could be the problem?
[fetch function for useSWR
using useSWR in a component](https://i.sstatic.net/pzXCQSKf.png)Using useSWR in Chrome[Using useSWR in FirefoxNetwork in FireFox (the request was not even sent)](https://i.sstatic.net/U4Nk89ED.png)
When using a GET request using useSWR, I want to receive the user's items, but the request is sent only in the Google Chrome browser, Yandex browser, and in FireFox and Safari requests are not sent, although they should

I had the same issue and checked my fetcher function that I used in useSWR. I found out that I set invalid custom header. Try to remove all custom headers.
